# I am confused with the definition of countable sets.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am confused with a quote in the textbook. It says "An infinite set is countable if and only if it is possible to list the elements of the set in a sequence (indexed by the positive integers)."

My question is that, is it ok to state an infinite set is countably infinite by arranging the elements of the set in a specific pattern, and assign each of them a positive integer?

For example, I wanted to prove that $A \cup B$ is a countable set given A and B are countably infinite sets.

Let $A= \{a_1, a_2,a_3,...,a_n,...\}$ and $B=\{ b_1, b_2,b_3,...,b_n,... \}$

Then, I can let $A /cup B={a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, ..., a_n, b_n, ...}$

and assign each elements a positive integer.

$$
a_1=1
, b_1=2
, a_2=3
, b_2=4
...
$$

Or I can rearrange the elements of $A \cup B$ so that it takes a new form: $\{ a_1, a_2, ..., a_n, ..., b_1, b_2, ..., b_n, ... \}$

and assign the positive integer in an increasing order, so that

$a_1=1,a_2=2, a_3=3, ...$

So, I hope you could understand what I am confused with. To sum up, I think I understand the idea "indexed by the positive integers." Much appreciated in advance.

Comment: You can assign the numbers in increasing order when it’s arranged like $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\ldots$ but not when it’s arranged like $a_1,a_2,\ldots,b_1,b_2,\ldots$

Comment: Your second list is not valid, since the first b never occurs on the list/

Comment: It means there is a bijective map $\phi: \mathbb{N} \to A \cup B$.

Comment: "Infinite by arranging the elements of the set in a specific pattern", it's not a matter of 'arranging,' it's more about 'assigning.' If in the new set, you are able to assign, to every member of the new set, a unique positive integer in a well-defined manner (using a function), the set is considered countable." it is infinite if you can assign every member of the set to a natural number, such that every natural number has been assigned with at least one member of the set.